# TSQL Improving queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Inherited two queries that are taking an age to run.  About 50 million rows in the table and no indexes.  The latter will be rectified and no doubt will improve performance, but any quick suggestions on making these more efficient?

```
Update OP_working
Set Is_fertility = 
(case
when PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_CLND in (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_2_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_3_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_4_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_5_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_6_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_7_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_8_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_9_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_10_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_11_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
or SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_12_CLND IN (select ICD10 from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10)
 then '1'

when PRIMARY_PROCEDURE_CODE in (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_1 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_2 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_3 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_4 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_5 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_6 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_7 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_8 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_9 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_10 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
OR SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_11 IN (select OPCS from dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS) 
then '1'
else '0'
end
)
```

and

```
update OP_working
 set derived_commissioner = 
 (case
when derived_commissioner_type = 'Private/Chargeable OSV' then 'VPP00'
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'CCG_of_practise' and GP_PRACTICE_CODE not in(select GP_PRACTICE_CODE from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes )then 'CCG_of_practise - unknown'
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'CCG_of_practise' then (select [PARENT_CODE] from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes where OP_working.GP_PRACTICE_CODE = CH_ref_practise_codes.GP_PRACTICE_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'AT_of_Provider' and provider_code not in (select provider_code from CH_ref_provider_codes) then 'AT_of_Provider - Unknown'
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'AT_of_Provider' then (select Commissioning_AT from dbo.CH_ref_provider_codes where OP_working.provider_code = CH_ref_provider_codes.ORG_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'Commissioning_AT_of_prison' and GP_PRACTICE_CODE not in (select GP_PRACTICE_CODE from CH_ref_prison_practises) then 'Commissioning_AT_of_prison - Unknown'
 when derived_commissioner_type = 'Commissioning_AT_of_prison' then (select [HUB_CODE] from dbo.CH_ref_prison_practises where OP_working.GP_PRACTICE_CODE = CH_ref_prison_practises.GP_PRACTICE_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner 
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'Dental - AT_of_CCG' and GP_PRACTICE_CODE not in  (select GP_PRACTICE_CODE from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes) then 'AT_of_CCG - Unknown'
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'Dental - AT_of_CCG' then (select [AREA_TEAM_CODE] from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes where OP_working.GP_PRACTICE_CODE = CH_ref_practise_codes.GP_PRACTICE_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'AT_of_CCG' and GP_PRACTICE_CODE not in  (select GP_PRACTICE_CODE from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes) then 'AT_of_CCG - Unknown'
 when derived_commissioner_type =  'AT_of_CCG' then (select [AREA_TEAM_CODE] from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes where OP_working.GP_PRACTICE_CODE = CH_ref_practise_codes.GP_PRACTICE_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner
 when derived_commissioner_type = 'Wales' then (select [PARENT_CODE] from dbo.CH_ref_practise_codes where OP_working.GP_PRACTICE_CODE = CH_ref_practise_codes.GP_PRACTICE_CODE)--+' - '+derived_commissioner


 else derived_commissioner_type
 end)
```

I was considering a join, rather than all the "select in", but just wanted some opinions first.

The version of SQL Server is 2012 as well.

Thanks

Comment: The statements are not very ... readable. The first statement will become a lot cleaner with the join. As for the second, if you have so many different values, you should put them in a reference table and join it with `OP_Working` to set the proper values

Comment: It looks like you're doing a lot of business logic in your SQL, if possible I would move it out to your business logic layer and simplify the SQL.

Comment: R Day - these are purely data crunching routines executed on a monthly basis when data is loaded.  There are no layers other than a SSIS package that call the procedure where the SQL resides

Comment: Agreed on the readability Panagiotis.  As mentioned, I've inherited code which was written by analysts rather than out and out sql developers.  So things like coding standards etc are an unknown to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can tell you the best way, unless you test them yourself. I would do this using temp tables like this:

```
DECLARE @ICD10 TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @OPCS TABLE ( ID INT )

INSERT  INTO @ICD10
        SELECT  ICD10
        FROM    dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10

INSERT  INTO @OPCS
        SELECT  OPCS
        FROM    dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS

UPDATE  OP_working
SET     Is_fertility = 0

UPDATE  w
SET     Is_fertility = 1
FROM    OP_working w
        JOIN @ICD10 t ON t.ID = PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_2_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_3_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_4_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_5_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_6_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_7_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_8_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_9_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_10_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_11_CLND
                         OR t.ID = SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_12_CLND

UPDATE  w
SET     Is_fertility = 1
FROM    OP_working w
        JOIN @OPCS t ON t.ID = PRIMARY_PROCEDURE_CODE
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_1
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_2
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_3
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_4
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_5
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_6
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_7
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_8
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_9
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_10
                        OR t.ID = SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_11
```

What about second statement, it is to complicated to try to optimize it. Try separating cases into different update statements.

Comment: May thanks Giorgi / Clausen, I totally agree with your comment Giorgi in that testing and playing is the only real way.  The issue was an analyst fired a series of queries off last night, so the server is being hammered by it (it's a live server, so didn't want to halt the batch of queries) and todays one of those where my brain doesn't want to work, so I unusually asked out in a lazy mode.  Agreed on the second statement too that having several statements would be the wiser way.  Both great answers guys and they have given my "no show" brain food for thought

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Is_fertility = coalesce(t2.x, t3.x, 0)
FROM OP_working t1
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT top 1 1 x 
FROM dbo.CH_ref_fertility_ICD10 
WHERE ICD10 IN 
  (t1.PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1_CLND,
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_2_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_3_CLND, 
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_4_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_5_CLND,
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_6_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_7_CLND,
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_8_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_9_CLND,
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_10_CLND, t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_11_CLND,
   t1.SECONDARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE_12_CLND)
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
) t2
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT top 1 1 x 
FROM dbo.CH_ref_fertility_OPCS 
WHERE OPCS IN 
  (t1.PRIMARY_PROCEDURE_CODE, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_1,
   t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_2, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_3,
   t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_4, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_5,
   t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_6, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_7,
   t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_8, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_9,
   t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_10, t1.SECONDARY_PROCEDURE_CODE_11)
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
) t3
```

Not sure this will work with 50 mil rows, but I think it is faster than your current script. Sorry, not going to try part 2